# UA Mystic: Nomadic Step movement after teleport?

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, unearthed-arcana

Ok, I'm confused about something and hoping there's some clarity on this.

The latest (v3) of UA Mystic, has the following power:

> **Nomadic Step**
>
> **Psychic Focus**. After you teleport on your turn while focused on this discipline, your walking speed increases by 10 feet until the end of the turn, as you are propelled by the magic of your teleportation. You can receive this increase only once per turn.

That appears fairly clear. So let's assume our character is focused on this ability.

Now, we just need to teleport ...

> **Step of a Dozen Paces (1–7 psi)**. If you haven’t moved yet on your turn, you take a bonus action to teleport up to 20 feet per psi point spent to an unoccupied space you can see, and your speed is reduced to 0 until the end of the turn.

Ok .. so Step of a Dozen Paces let's us teleport 20 ft/pp, but reduces are speed to 0.
However, Our Pyschic Focus ability boosts our speed +10 for being focused ...

soo ... if I spend 1 pp ... can I teleport 20 ft and move 10 ft ? or am I just stuck at the 20 ft teleport ??

(I'm guessing the latter, but hoping I'm wrong :) )

It seems really odd that these abilities - both within the same discipline - seem to contradict each other ... "hey, here's an ability .. but oh .. you can't benefit from it"  O.o

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can (probably) move 10 feet after you teleport with Step of a Dozen Paces. Firstly, from Step of a Dozen Paces:

> you take a bonus action to teleport [...] **and** your speed is reduced to 0 until the end of your turn.

And secondly, from Nomadic Step:

> **After** you teleport on your turn while focused on this discipline, your walking speed increases by 10 feet [...]

I bolded the "and" in Step of a Dozen Paces and the "after" in Nomadic Step, because they're important. "And" implies that the speed reduction happens concurrently with the teleport, while "after" implies that the speed increase happens, well, *after* the teleport.

So you teleport, and your speed becomes 0. Sucks to be you, I guess. But then, after the teleport (and the corresponding speed loss), your speed is boosted by 10. This leaves you with a speed of 10 feet, allowing you to move. Hooray!

Comment: I believe you have the intent and reasoning correct, and state it more clearly than Jeremy and Mike did in the UA itself.

Comment: @JAStreich Thanks! I'm just glad that the timing allows us to sidestep the contradiction.

Comment: @Miniman: I agree with J.A.Streich .. nice answer .. and well put ... :)  I'll let this digest and sink in and give others time to chime in ..